# IntellidjIdea и JAR

Tags: ide, java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как создать jar-файл в IntellidjIdea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File/Project Structure,  **
дальше переходите на вкладку Artifacts, там настраиваете экспорт в Jar. В остальном догадаетесь, я думаю. Вот скриншот:

[image]

Comment: Спасибо за ответы @Антон Мухин и @Artem Prigoda

Answer (score 1):

Установите соответствующий [плагин](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=256) для Idea. Ну или с помощью Maven'a можно, если знаете как с ним работать.